# Google Sheet Pivot Table Calculated field - Glitches

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a project that requires multiple pivot tables all connected to Data Slicers to aggregate the data various cuts. While adding a calculated field column in ANY of my pivot tables, a few seconds into writing the custom formula, my cursor kicks me out of the fomula, then I get an error (error is because I wasn't done writing the formula and it's not quite completed).

I've been getting used to this "glitch" in google sheets, but it seems like google sheets is calculating every few seconds and if you're not actively typing in the formula box for more than 1-2 seconds, then it kicks you out and calculates whatever you have typed out. Super frustrating when you have many of these formulas to write.

Does anyone know of any workarounds for this?

[Here is an example of the "caculated field" box that times out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfGsG.png)

Attempts:

- I've tried changing the "Summerize by" field to "Custom" prior to writing out the formula, but the calculated field seems very glitchy.
- I've also tried changing the recalculation settings to "On change and every minute" hoping this might help which it did not.